# IOS App Extend trial period from server

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

we are implementing an app that controls user login from our servers. We offer a trial period of 7 days after which we prompt the user to buy the non renewable subscription. After payment and receipt validation we call our servers to increase the trial period for specified time.

What stops us from increasing the trial period of few users I know by a specified time or rather indefinitely from backend so that they keep using it for free without apple knowing it?

Comment: FYI you might have an issue getting this app accepted on to the App Store as Apple does not allow trial periods in apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786767/apple-trial-periods-are-they-allowed

Comment: But the app needs a user to login to access private data inside the app, which I guess needs to be controlled from external servers only. we have already been rejected due to "Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices". So we had to put in a trial period of 7 days. What is another way of implementing this?